# Hibernate - Session.createQuery(String) returns null after upgrade

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, tapestry

Upgraded an old application running Tapestry v5.4.5 -> v5.8.2, we get issues with Hibernate/HQL queries.

A query like this that used to work

```
session.createQuery("from MyEntity", MyEntity.class)
```

Is now throwing exception:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.query.Query.list()" because the return value of "org.hibernate.Session.createQuery(String, java.lang.Class)" is null`

All our Hibernate is in the `hibernate.cfg.xml`

Anyone know why this happens?

As a fun fact, using a `EntityManager` seems to work fine though:

```
session.getEntityManagerFactory()
                .createEntityManager()
                .createQuery("select e from MyEntity e", MyEntity.class)
                .getResultList()
```

Comment: Tapestry 5.4.5 uses 4.3.6.Final whereas Tapestry 5.8.2 uses Hibernate 5.4.32.Final. I'm not a Hibernate expert, but I'm guessing the problem is caused by something that changed within Hibernate, rather than Tapestry.

Comment: More fun facts - session.createCriteria(MyEntity.class).list() works, you can also get by with session.getSession().createQuery(). For details see here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-2754

Comment: @VangelV.Ajanovski - thanks for linking to the bug report. Seems like such a big deal I was sure it was something I had done wrong on my part.